# Webstorm- Nodemon + Typescript + Docker - debugger connected but breakpoints not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, debugging, nodemon

I have a node project written in typescript. The process runs inside a docker container using Nodemon. node (via nodemon) is run inside the container with the `--inspect` option.
When I try to connect with Webstorm to the process, it connects but no breakpoints are being hit.

This command used in the `package.json` to start:
`tsc-watch --incremental --onFirstSuccess "sh -c 'tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s ./src -o ./dist/src && nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 dist/src/main.js --config nodemon-debug.json'" --onSuccess "sh -c 'tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s ./src -o ./dist/src && touch ./dist/src/main.js`

Explanation:
use tsc-watch to to watch for changes in code.
After first build success run `tscpaths` to replace path shortcuts, then run nodemon with the `inspect` option (which is passed to node).
After each build success run `tscpaths` and touch the `main.js` file to trigger nodemon to restart the process.

nodemon config (watch only `main.js` file which is touched after every build by `tsc-watch`):

```
{
  "watch": [
    "./dist/src/main.js"
  ],
  "ext": "js"
}
```

Port 9229 of the docker container is mapped to port 9666 on the host machine in the `docker-compose.yml`, and in Webstorm I use the "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" configuration to attach to localhost port 9666.

The `tsconfig.json` file includes `"sourceMap": true`.

This whole process of automatic build + restart on every code change works.
The debugger is attached in Webstorm (The Debugger tab says "Connected to localhost:9666 - dist/src/main.js").
The problem is that no breakpoints are being hit. They are not marked with a "V" and are not being hit during execution.

Any ideas?

Using Webstorm 2021.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you need to set up in the debugger.

Take a look at the config, and there's something called **Remote URLs of local files(optional)**. You need to specifiy the RemoteURL for your file/directory so it can hit the debugger.

[sample config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21F5X.png)